# Storing data using array reference

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference

I have a file looks like this

### ConfigFile

```
run Test3
run Test1
```

### TestDir File

```
{

home/usera/aa/TestFile1
home/usera/aa/TestFile2

}
```

### TestFile1

```
Test 1
{
  Command1 Value
  Command2 Value
}

Test2
{
  Command4 Value
  Command1 Value
  Sleep    4
  Command5 Value
}
```

### TestFile2

```
Test 3
{
  Command3 Value
  Sleep    4
}

Test8
{
 Command9  Value
  Command10 Value
  Sleep     2 
}
```

what I want to do is open each TestFile and read it and just store the data within the {..}
in a Test hash having key as Testname(ie.Test1,Test3) and value for the key would be the command value pair withing the test

Can anyone help me out.Thanks

Comment: This would work better if you could provide the actual data structure you want to create. Also: what have you tried to create that data structure, and why did your code fail?

Comment: This is not a programming tutorial site. Post what you've tried and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if your data file format has been decided arbitrarily? It is a dreadful design, and you should stick with it only if you are constrained to using it, say by a third party. If you have a choice then there are many established data file formats and you should simply adopt one of those. JSON is deservedly popular at the moment and there are [excellent Perl modules](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) to handle it available from CPAN.

If you decide to stick with your original design then this program will do what you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my (%tests, $commands, $test);

for my $file (qw/ testfile1.txt testfile2.txt /) {
  open my $fh, '<', $file;
  while (<$fh>) {
    s/\s+\z//;
    if (/\{/) {
      $commands = [];
    }
    elsif (/\}/) {
      $tests{$test} = $commands if $test and @$commands;
      $commands = undef;
    }
    elsif ($commands) {
      push @$commands, [ split ' ', $_, 2 ] if /\S/;
    }
    else {
      $test = $1 if /(\S(?:.*\S)?)/;
    }
  }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%tests;
```

**output**

```
{
  "Test 1" => [["Command1", "Value"], ["Command2", "Value"]],
  "Test 3" => [["Command3", "Value"], ["Sleep", 4]],
  "Test2"  => [
                ["Command4", "Value"],
                ["Command1", "Value"],
                ["Sleep", 4],
                ["Command5", "Value"],
              ],
  "Test8"  => [["Command9", "Value"], ["Command10", "Value"], ["Sleep", 2]],
}
```

Comment: Thanks it should get me going

Answer (score -1):

You could write your own parser, but you're not likely to have a good time. If you convert your data files to [JSON](https://metacpan.org/release/JSON) or [YAML](https://metacpan.org/release/YAML), then you'll be able to read your files into memory without much hassle.